# python weekday and strftime("%U")

Tags: python

Is there a workaround for the following

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
a = datetime.now() # <== 2016-03-09 11:06:04.824047 

print a.strftime("%U")
>>> 10

#go back to previous Sunday
b = a - timedelta(days = 3)

print b.strftime("%U")
>>> 10
print b.weekday()
>>> 6
```

Shouldn't `b.strftime("%U")` be `9` as it the last day of the week?

Comment: Weeks are starting on Sunday for `%U`.

Answer (score 2):

`%U` treats weeks as starting on *Sunday*, not on Monday. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> `%U`
>   Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

You could use the `%W` format, which gives a zero-padded week number based on *Monday* being the first day of the week:

> `%W`
>   Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.

The alternative is to use `b.isocalendar()[1]` if you need to get the week number as per ISO 8601. The rules for what is considered week 1 differ from the ISO calendar calculations; `%W` bases this on the first Monday in the year, while ISO 8601 states that the week that includes January 4 is the first week. For 2016 both systems align, but that's not the case in 2014, 2015 or 2019:

```
>>> d = datetime(2019, 3, 9)
>>> d.strftime('%W')
'09'
>>> d.isocalendar()[1]
10
```

If you wait until Python 3.6, you can use the `%V` format to include the ISO week number, see [issue 12006](http://bugs.python.org/issue12006).

Comment: or %W i.e  b.strftime("%W")

Comment: @Cos: but that's a different week numbering scheme.